# Mocking using pytest for class method is not working

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Following is my Class `main.py`

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        ret_val = self.do_verify()
        print(ret_val['value'])
        if ret_val['value'] is False:
            raise Exception
        print('works in object')

    def do_verify(self):
        return {'value': True}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    First()
```

When I run `python3 main.py` it prints
`True \n works in object`

Following is my test case `test_main.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

from main import First


def fake_do_verify():
    print('works')
    return {'value': False}

class TestMain(object):
    
    @patch.object(First, 'do_verify', autospec=True)
    def test_main(self, fake_do_verify):
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            First()
```

This is failing my test case. I am not sure what exactly I am missing. It should passes the test case as mocking is making value False.

```
=================================================== FAILURES ====================================================
______________________________________________ TestMain.test_main _______________________________________________

self = <test_main.TestMain object at 0x7f98190a39e8>, fake_do_verify = <function do_verify at 0x7f98190d1158>

    @patch.object(First, 'do_verify', autospec=True)
    def test_main(self, fake_do_verify):
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
>           First()
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>

test_main.py:17: Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fake_do_verify()` function that you defined is not used at all; what `@patch` is doing is create a MagicMock to patch `First.do_verify`. The mock object returns another mock when called, which returns another mock when indexed, which evaluates as False when compared against False with the `is` operator.

If you want to patch with your function, you can do it as follows (but change `fake_do_verify` to take a `self` argument):

```
    @patch.object(First, 'do_verify', fake_do_verify)
    def test_main(self):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could do without defining that function, leave the patch as you originally had it, but set the return value of the mock object:

```
    @patch.object(First, 'do_verify', autospec=True)
    def test_main(self, fake_do_verify):
        fake_do_verify.return_value = {'value': False}
        ...
```